# AJAX get origin of visitor

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, request, xmlhttprequest

Assume that a visitor that browses website B makes an AJAX request to my website, website A. Is it possible for me to detect the IP address / domain name of the website he is browsing?

Comment: Yes. Browser sends the domain name in origin field of request headers. You can check it in req.headers.origin.

Comment: And this cannot be modified by the user?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX call is all same with default call except reloading the whole web page.

You can do everything in AJAX call.

There's no relationship between AJAX call and detecting IP address.